# Display ads to visitors who are coming from facebook only

Tags: javascript, php, adsense

I want to display ads only to visitors who are coming from facebook. I found here a code but does not work. Could you please help me fix the problems on this script

```
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:block"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
     data-ad-slot="4357587803"
     data-ad-format="auto"
     data-full-width-responsive="true"></ins> 
<script type="text/javascript">
        if (document.referrer.match(/facebook/)) {
            // Show the ins-block
            document.getElementsByClassName('adsbygoogle')[0].style.display = 'inline-block';
            // Load adsense-javascript using
            var script = document.createElement('script');
            script.src = "//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"; // Note: different url due to async
            script.async = true; // Not necessary, but speeds up loading your page
            var firstScript = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            firstScript.parentNode.insertBefore(script, firstScript);
        } </script>
```

Comment: I don't think Facebook sends referrers these days, but I do believe they set a `fbclid` in the query string on all links. Look for that.

Comment: yes in link writed fbclid but when check analytics i see referer is facebook.com

Comment: I have tried using fbclid instead facebook but didn't worked

Comment: I need your answer please guys

Answer (score 0):

You can check the url parameter `fbclid` is present in the url and decide the ad space is printed or removed. This can be easily done using php.

This is the sample code:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['fbclid'])){
        // Print your ad code
        print '<ins class="adsbygoogle"
               style="display:block"
               data-ad-client="ca-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
               data-ad-slot="4357587803"
               data-ad-format="auto"
               data-full-width-responsive="true"></ins>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: it worked but when the link hasn't fbclid tag will not work and in mobilee you must fbclid tag to work

Comment: and another question how to add other sources like pinterest

Comment: Normally if the user comes through fb, there is fbclid tag. Because it is used for analytics and many more. So you don't need to worry about that.

Comment: If you want to track any source, you can add UTM parameters for the link. As an exampale, my link is `www.example.com/page` but instead of that I put `www.example.com/page?utm-source=pinterest` so I can check the utm parameter and find the users origination.

Comment: could you please modify the script which i have pasted in the post because this one which you sent me work only in the first page and i am breaking posts to many pages that's why will not help me this script

Comment: Ok... That needs more php code and techniques. How can I help you? Github?

Comment: Do you mean that i need to pay you for that?

Comment: No no... Code is quite long. How can I send it to you?

Comment: you can paste it here www.pastiebin.com